# Stripe Wordpress Invoice

Tags: wordpress, payment-gateway, invoice, stripe-payments

I'm using **stripe gateway** for my payment process everything is fine but the sad part is the **customer need the invoice** so that they have the **proof of the payment**.

I tried searching for plugins in the wordpress most of them are woo-commerce based but i really don't use the woo-commerce any where and i don't prefer that. is there any plugin to generate **invoice automatically** and send it to the sender email id? even if it is pro version also i can manage.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable emails for successful payments in your dashboard settings: https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/emails

You can do the same for invoices in your subscription settings: https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/billing/automatic